# Does Team foundation 2013 support lower version like sql server 2008 R2?

Tags: tfs

Does Team Foundation 2013 support lower version like SQL Server 2008 R2

If not, is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

No it does not support SQL 2008 R2.

> Team Foundation Server requires SQL Server 2012 with Service Pack 1 or
>   the next version of SQL Server.

You can check the requirements [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd631889.aspx) (SQL) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592.aspx) (OS).

I very much doubt there is a workaround as Microsoft will have built upon SQL 2012 server and language features.